# Kotlin: Как увеличивать значение типа Double с помощью *=?

Tags: kotlin

Не понимаю как увеличивать в прогрессии значение типа `Double` не переводя это все в `Int`, т.к. `Int` округлит, а `*=` просит значение типа `Int`: `Type mismatch. Required: Int Found: Double`

Вот пример:

```
private var upgradeCost = 100
private var currentCost = upgradeCost
private var multiplier = 1.2

private fun makePurchase(){
   currentCost *= multiplier
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
upgradeCost = 100.0
```